# How to scrape a website from opensea using node js

Tags: node.js, request, opensea

I'm failing at trying to scrape a collection of polygon NFTs from Opensea. Could someone please provide an example that prints the html returned in console? I tried the code below:

```
const https = require("https");

https.get("https://opensea.io/collection/orathai", response => {
        console.log(response)

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

axios.get('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/orathai/?format=json')
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    });
```

don't forget : npm i axios

Refrence :

[opensea api docs](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-collections)

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Hi, thanks - sadly the Opensea API currently does not seem to support Polygon...

Comment: hello , could you edit your qs so i can clearly help you show us exemple of the output you want